# Introducing Physics.SE University Ambassadors Program: calling students and teachers

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

StackExchange is looking for students and teachers who might be interested in helping us kick off/formalize a university pizza ambassador-type program. Physics.StackExchange would like to sponsor university students (college or graduate) and faculty members who are excited about Physics, Stack Exchange and free food. Contact Seth Rogers (email seth at stackexchange or drop a note in chat) for more details about the program and to get involved.

Students at all levels learn from these type of gatherings; interesting questions help Physics as a discipline and Stack Exchange as a growing resource.

Comment: I like this idea, and I'm hoping it catches on. Anyone else who is interested, I'd be happy to discuss plans in [chat].